# Difftime returns 0 all the time

Tags: c, mktime

At the beginning I want to highlight that I've already read all similar posts in stack overflow. And nothing helped me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T 1
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct tm beg;
  struct tm aft;
  beg.tm_hour=0; beg.tm_min=0; beg.tm_sec=0;
  aft.tm_hour=11; aft.tm_min=19; aft.tm_sec=19;
  long long c;
  c=difftime(mktime(&aft),mktime(&beg));
  printf("%lld",c);
  return 0;
 }
```

It all the timr print out 0 an nothing else, but when I tried to change mktime(&aft) to time now time(&now) I got non-zero result. What should I correct in this code?

Comment: Try `struct tm beg = { 0 }; struct tm aft = { 0 };`. Perhaps `mktime` is failing because of the uninitialized junk values in the other fields.

Comment: You could check for this by doing `time_t t1 = mktime(&aft);  if ( t1 == -1 ) { printf("mktime failed!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` etc.

Comment: Exactly. The values of the other fields of `beg` and `aft` are garbage because you haven't assigned values to them.

Comment: Unfortunately assigning values didnt change anything. When I tried to compile it in online compiler everything was alright.

Comment: @KeithThompson you was right - this function failed.

Comment: But in another compiler everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the argument passed to mktime references a date before midnight, January 1, 1970, or if the calendar time cannot be represented, the function returns –1 cast to type time_t.
([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246472(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246472%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

This could be causing the mktime to fail because the tm_year variable in beg and aft are invalid.

Setting this variable to a value that represents a year after 1970 produced the intended result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T 1
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm beg = {0};
    struct tm aft = {0};

    beg.tm_hour=0; beg.tm_min=0; beg.tm_sec=0;
    beg.tm_year = 71;  //Set to 1971

    aft.tm_hour=11; aft.tm_min=19; aft.tm_sec=19;
    aft.tm_year = 71;  //Set to 1971

    long long c;
    c=difftime(mktime(&aft),mktime(&beg));
    printf("%lld",c);
        return 0;
}
```